# JavaScript window #hash actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links on the page

```
<a href="#Form">Form</a>
<a href="#Image">Image</a>
```

I made a simple click.

```
$('a[href="#Form"]').on('click',function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

also I'd like HASH works as well.

```
if(window.location.hash = "#Form"){alert("hi");}
```

Once the page loads, it shows ALERT, then I click Image link, the url becomes `www.myweb.com/#Image`, if I press  (history) button, the url looks `www.myweb.com/#Form` BUT `alert("hi")` isn't working anymore.

Can I make it still works even I press  button?

Comment: You would need to bind an onhashchange listener and/or use the History API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    if(document.location.hash == '#Form'){
        alert('hi')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First your condition is wrong:-

```
if(window.location.hash = "#Form"){alert("hi");}

to 

if(window.location.hash == "#Form"){alert("hi");}
```

Other thing you need to bind hashchange event. Not all browsers support this event. In that case you need to check hash changes using setInterval function of javascript.